# ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture() loses uri when rotating screen

Tags: android, kotlin

I am building an app that calls an activity to analyze a photo. once that activity starts it launches the camera or gallery depending on the value of "capture" or "gallery". the problem is:
I want to keep the activity orientation in **portrait** but the camera follows the phone orientation and after taking the photo it loses everything and starts the camera again OnResume again and again. if I held the phone vertically and captured the pic everything works fine and the pic appears in 
Any changing of the rotation gets me error **W/ImageView: Unable to open content: content://com.myProject.projecttwo.provider/external/Android/media/com.myProject.projecttwo/projectTwo/2021-07-31-17-59-19-4262257504715507656821.jpeg**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import java.io.File
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

class PhotoAnalysis : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var receivedUriKey: Uri? = null
    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
    //private var selection: String? = null
    private var selection: String? = "capture" /* later will get it from clicks*/
    private lateinit var imageView: ImageView

    private val pickerContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
        if(uri != null) { receivedUriKey = uri}
    }

    private val capturePicture = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) {
        if(it) {
            receivedUriKey.let { uri ->
                if( uri != null) {
                    receivedUriKey = uri
                    Log.d("Capture Pic", receivedUriKey.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_analysis)

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.result_image_view)

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        if( selection == "gallery" && receivedUriKey == null) {
            pickerContent.launch("image/*")
        } else if(selection == "capture" && receivedUriKey == null) {
            Log.d("Capture Resume", receivedUriKey.toString())
            takeImage()
        }
        if(receivedUriKey != null) {
            Log.d("Capture Resume 2", receivedUriKey.toString())
            imageView.setImageURI(receivedUriKey)
        }
    }


    private fun takeImage() {
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            getTmpFileUri().let { uri ->
                receivedUriKey = uri
                capturePicture.launch(uri)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getTmpFileUri(): Uri {
        outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory(this)
        val tmpFile = File.createTempFile(
            SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME, Locale.ENGLISH).format(System.currentTimeMillis()), PHOTO_EXTENSION, outputDirectory).apply {
            createNewFile()
            deleteOnExit()
        }
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider", tmpFile)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val FILENAME = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        private const val PHOTO_EXTENSION = ".jpeg"

        private fun getOutputDirectory(context: Context): File {
            val appContext = context.applicationContext
            val mediaDir = context.externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
                File(it, appContext.resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() } }
            return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
                mediaDir else appContext.filesDir
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Save the `uri` in your `ViewModel` class. Follow the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Override onSaveInstanceState() to save the value of variables. Then in onCreate take them from the bundle parameter back.

Comment: I did override onSaveInstanceState() but somehow the activity is rebuilt without saving it, or saving a uri which can't be used and return a "bad uri error" and the app stop